# Automatically adjustable layout (having ListView) at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have an activity with dialog theme. Its layout has 3 parts

---

**HEADER**

---

---

**BODY (HAS ListView)**

---

---

**OK BUTTON**

---

This has to be the structure of my layout always. If I use following layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dip" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_av_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/tablet_ic_logo" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_av_found"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/iv_av_logo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="16dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_av_found"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_av_recommendation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_av_found"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_av_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rl_av_found"
        android:background="@drawable/tablet_dialog_glow" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_av_threats_found"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="@drawable/tablet_dialog_separator" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_button_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_av_body" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_av_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/btn_ok" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_separator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/tablet_dialog_footer" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It gives me what I want. But if the list grows and I have say 100 items, OK button goes out of the picture.

And if I use this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dip" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_av_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/tablet_ic_logo" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_av_found"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/iv_av_logo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingLeft="16dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_av_found"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_av_recommendation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_av_found"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_button_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_av_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/btn_ok" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_separator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/tablet_dialog_footer" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_av_threats"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/rl_button_bar"
        android:layout_below="@id/rl_av_found"
        android:background="@drawable/tablet_dialog_glow" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_av_found"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="@drawable/tablet_dialog_separator" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The OK button is always displayed at the bottom of the screen and the layout's height takes full screen even if I have just one item in the ListView.

**How should I structure my xml so as to have its height wrapped according to the content and OK button always visible independent of the number of items in the ListView?**

Answer (score 0):

By Default you should have the params as,
Header - Align Top
Body(ListView) - Below header,
Button - below body(ListView)

Now at runtime,
You should get the height of the list view and if it goes beyond the screen, and if it does, then Set the layout params of button to alignParentBottom and layout params of list view to be below header and above button.
Use may use this in vice versa.

To get the height of the list view. Use this

```
public int getTotalListViewHeight(ListView lv, BaseAdapter ba) {
        int listviewElementsheight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ba.getCount(); i++) {
            View view = ba.getView(i, null, lv);
            view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            listviewElementsheight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
            // for Width use view.getMeasuredWidth()
        }
        return listviewElementsheight;
    }
```

Here the adapter is listviews adapter.

also will checking this, add the buttons height to the total height.